# Let $V$ be a vector space. If $\lbrace v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3} \rbrace$ is spanning, is $\lbrace v_{1}+v_{2}, v_{2}+v_{3}, v_{3}+v_{1} \rbrace$ spanning?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not sure where to start. The only thing I know is that for the first vector of the set $\lbrace v_{1}+v_{2}, v_{2}+v_{3}, v_{3}+v_{1} \rbrace$, if I were to remove $v_{2}$, I would have to subtract $v_{2}+v_{3}$. But then I would get $v_{3}$ so then I would have to add the third vector, etc. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Start with the definition of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ being a spanning set.  Aim toward the definition of the desired conclusion, that $\{v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,v_3+v_1\}$ is a spanning set.  In particular, does the latter set allow us to express the elements of the first set as linear combinations?

Comment: You can use a multi-linearity argument to show the determinant is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $v_1 = (1,0,0)$, $v_2 = (0,1,0)$ and $v_3 = (0,0,1)$ and try to visualize the vectors $v_1 + v_2$, $v_1 + v_3$, and $v_2 + v_3$ in $3$-space.

Algebraically, we see $(1,0,0) \rightarrow (1,1,0)$, $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (0,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1) \rightarrow (1,0,1)$ is the map from $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\} \rightarrow \{v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, v_1 + v_3\}$ and the reverse map $(1,0,0) \rightarrow (1/2, -1/2, 1/2)$, $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (1/2, 1/2, -1/2)$ and $(0,0,1) \rightarrow (-1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$ is the inverse $\{v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, v_1 + v_3\} \rightarrow \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

Comment: This only works if the scalar field has characteristic $\ne 2$.

Comment: Oh yes, when the scalar field has characteristic 2, I don't believe $\{v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, v_1 + v_3\}$ spans the vector space. The easiest way to see this is by looking at the determinant of the first (or second) linear transformation that I gave.

Comment: At least it doesn't span *in general*.  But it's still certainly *possible* for $\{ v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, v_1 + v_3 \}$ to span $V$ (since the problem statement says nothing about linear independence of $v_1, v_2, v_3$): for example, if $V = \mathbb{F}_2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $v_1 = 1, v_2 = v_3 = 0$.

Comment: I am so pleased to be in a place where I do not have to work with such nuisances. Everything in commutative algebra works the way I want it to work hehe

Answer (score 0):

I think yes? Haven't done math in a long time but...

Let $\upsilon = a(\upsilon_{1}) + b(\upsilon_{2}) + c(\upsilon_{3})$

and

$\upsilon = d(\upsilon_{1}+\upsilon_{2}) + e(\upsilon_{2}+\upsilon_{3}) + f(\upsilon_{2}+\upsilon_{3})$

After substitution I get $a = d + f, b = d + e, c = e + f$. This system of equations has explicit solutions of $d = \frac{(a + b - c)}{2}, e = \frac{(-a + b + c)}{2}, f = \frac{(a - b + c)}{2}$

Therefore there is an injection of {${\upsilon_{1}+\upsilon_{2}, \upsilon_{2}+\upsilon_{3}, \upsilon_{2}+\upsilon_{3}}$} on {${\upsilon_{1}, \upsilon_{2}, \upsilon_{3}}$}.

Comment: This only works if the scalar field doesn't have characteristic 2.  (Granted, it's possible the OP's course is only considering scalar field of $\mathbb{R}$, or maybe restricting scalar field to be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ - but it's not clear whether that's the case or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Given $x\in V$, you want to write it as $x=a(v_1+v_2)+b(v_2+v_3)+c(v_3+v_1)$. This becomes
$$
x=(a+c)v_1+(a+b)v_2+(b+c)v_3
$$
The information you have is that $x=pv_1+qv_2+rv_3$, for some $p$, $q$ and $r$.

Can you find $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the equalities
\begin{cases}
a+c=p \\
a+b=q \\
b+c=r
\end{cases}
hold? This is a linear system and row reduction gives
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & p \\
1 & 1 & 0 & q \\
0 & 1 & 1 & r
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & p \\
0 & 1 & -1 & q-p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & r
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & p \\
0 & 1 & -1 & q-p \\
0 & 0 & -2 & r-q+p
\end{array}\right]
$$
Can you finish?

A (not so) different strategy is to show that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ can be written as linear combinations of $v_1+v_2$, $v_2+v_3$ and $v_3+v_1$, which seems your attempt. You can notice that writing $v_1=a(v_1+v_2)+b(v_2+v_3)+c(v_3+v_1)$ corresponds to the above computation with $p=1$, $q=r=0$. Similarly for $v_2$ and $v_3$.

Thus the generic method above seems better, doesn't it?

Comment: For the method involving the matrix, I simply have to reduce it to the identity matrix and if not, is it not spanning?

Comment: @AustinYue It's not necessary to go on with the elimination: at the stage I stopped, it is already known that the system has a solution.